# Unexpected Exception error 'NonType'

Tags: lubuntu

Whenever I tried to run `ansible --version` it shows me below error.

[image]

It is something like [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/31249), but there is no solution for this.

Comment: Please do not post text as picture. Post text as text and use the formatting tools to outline code snippets.

Comment: @Thomas I can understand but I can't copy and paste from virtual box to real OS. thats why I captured the screen and share here.

Comment: It looks like you try *ansible 2.6.0*? [According to here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/CHANGELOG.md) that version is under active development. You may want to open a bug at ansible instead?

Comment: @Thomas Yeah it is ansible 2.6. Whenever I tried to get ansible , it installed ansible 2.6. So it there any other method to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 3):

1. Ansible is [well packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=ansible) in Ubuntu:

> **Package ansible**
>
> ```
> trusty (14.04LTS) (admin): Configuration management, deployment, and task execution system [universe]
> 1.5.4+dfsg-1: all
> trusty-backports (admin): Configuration management, deployment, and task execution system [universe]
> 1.7.2+dfsg-1~ubuntu14.04.1: all
> xenial (16.04LTS) (admin): Configuration management, deployment, and task execution system [universe]
> 2.0.0.2-2: all
> xenial-updates (admin): Configuration management, deployment, and task execution system [universe]
> 2.0.0.2-2ubuntu1: all
> xenial-backports (admin): Configuration management, deployment, and task execution system [universe]
> 2.1.1.0-1~ubuntu16.04.1: all
> artful (admin): Configuration management, deployment, and task execution system [universe]
> 2.3.1.0+dfsg-2: all
> bionic (admin): Configuration management, deployment, and task execution system [universe]
> 2.3.1.0+dfsg-2: all
> ```

2. If you really need to install newer version you should run

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-pip
   sudo pip install ansible
   sudo pip install paramiko
   ```

   This results in

   ```
   $ ansible --version
   ansible 2.4.3.0
     config file = None
     configured module search path = [u'/home/xenial/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
     ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
     executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
     python version = 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
   ```

Comment: I tried the command that you mentioned in the point 2. But still I am getting same error.

Comment: Then you should remove all wrong installed pip packages (check with `pip list`).

Comment: Yeah its `setuptools` that i installed to build and install the `ansible`. If i remove this `setuptools` then it shows no error but it shows backtrace. If i wont install these `setuptools` then the ansible doesn't  build

Comment: Traceback logs are different if i remove `setuptools` and  it shows me no `setuptools` found and it is required for ansible. These setuptools contain python.

Comment: It is your system, not mine. You trashed it, not me. I can't help more.

Comment: It is a deadlock type situation bro. for ansible i need setuptools, but it shows me error.

Comment: @dahiya_boy th crux or N0rbert's answer is that you don't need to build ansible. You should remove any problematic packages and install ansible with APT